# Add Property to Object in loop with Lodash in Express

Tags: json, express, lodash

I need to add a "id" property converted in kebab-case to an object parsed from a JSON file:

**App.js**

```
    app.get('/factions', (req, res) => {
      const rawData = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/views/data/factions.json');
      var factions = JSON.parse(rawData);

      for (var key in factions) {
          factions.key["id"] = _.kebabCase(key);
      }

      console.log(factions);

    res.render('pages/factions', {
        factionList: factions
      });
    });
```

This way doesn't work, if I try `factions["Faction One"]["id"] = _.kebabCase(key);` I can see `"id" : "faction-one"` is added to `Faction One`. But if I use the key value doesn't.

**JSON**

```
{
  "Faction One": {
    "color": "blue"
  },
  "Faction Two": {
    "color": "red"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
for (var key in factions) {

 factions[key].id = _.kebabCase(key);

}
```